# Show warning on a single node

Tags: angular, treeview

**Intro** -
I'm building a tree-view that dynamically loads and displays a nested data set. Here you can find the code:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">

<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding >
  <button mat-icon-button [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
      {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
  {{node.item}}
  <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="node.isLoading" mode="indeterminate" class="example-tree-progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
  <app-error *ngIf="error" [text] = "errorText"></app-error> // I'm struggling with this particular line
</mat-tree-node>
```

**The problem** - When the toggled node cannot be expanded, I need to show a red box that says "no available data". The box has to be displayed *only* under the toggled node.

I managed to inform the user about the issue, but not to target the toggled node. In the following picture you can see what happens.

[image: This is what I've achieved so far.]

**Question** - What can I adjust in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you show the error if `error` evaluates `true` (there's something in it), but it's the same variable for all nodes.
This way you either display the error in all nodes, or in none of them.

If you want it to be displayed only on selected nodes, I would expect the condition inside your `*ngIf` contain something that is inside the node object like `node.hasError` or `!node.data`.